# OmniAuth Authentication failure! timeout: Timeout::Error, execution expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, devise, omniauth

Using OmniAuth 1.1.0 with Devise 2.0.4 I'm getting this error when trying to connect to Twitter:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/twitter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-23 14:50:23 -0400
(twitter) Callback phase initiated.
(twitter) Callback phase initiated.
(twitter) Authentication failure! timeout: Timeout::Error, execution expired
```

Which then leads OmniAuth to call

```
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
```

Interestingly though, I'm getting the user's info as a part of `request.env["omniauth.auth"]`. That is, request.env contains the user's real Twitter profile data -- even though OmniAuth says it has timed out. Can someone provide me with a clue as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had initially been upgrading to OmniAuth 1.1.0 with Devise 2.0.4 from versions 0.4.7 and 1 respectively, so what I did to fix this problem is first roll back my changes, and then redo the updates of the gems. I think it had been some manual tinkering with my Gemfile that had screwed this one up.

If you're getting complaints about rack dependencies when upgrading, try removing the block about sinatra from your Gemfile (not the lines that mention sinatra as a dependency, but rather the block that mentions sinatra and its dependencies) and then running a bundle install or update or whatever.